# In Drupal 7's Workbench module, how do I set permissions for editing content by its current transition state?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, workbench, drupal-permissions

In Drupal 7's Workbench module, how do I set permissions for editing content by its current state?  For example, I want to prevent an authenticated user from being able to edit his own content when the content is in the Needs Review state, while still allowing them to edit their own content in the Draft state.  Basically, I need a way to specify view and edit permissions for different roles by the current transition state of the content.  How do I do this?